# Can I boost the volume above 100% without going into System Settings?

Tags: sound

Is there a tweak that allows me to boost the volume above 100% without having to go to `System Settings` -> `Sound` every time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

r3bl's answer does not work on the latest version of Elementary OS

Essentially what you need to do now is:

1. Install `dconf-editor`
2. Run dconf-editor as YOUR user, NOT sudo / root
3. Navigate to `/io/elementary/desktop/wingpanel/sound/max-volume`
4. Toggle `Use Defaults` to `False`
5. Change max to number of your choice
6. Navigate to `/org/gnome/desktop/sound`
7. Toggle `Use Defaults` to `False`
8. Make current value `True` (this seems to allow the use of the keyboard shortcuts for volume)
9. Exit

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Surprisingly, yes!

First, open up `dconf-editor` (if you don't have it yet, you can install it with `sudo apt-get install dconf-editor`).

Then, navigate through `com` -> `ubuntu` -> `sound` and enable the `allow-amplified-volume` option.

By doing so, you'll be able to increase the volume above 100% by using the Wingpanel's sound indicator. However, you still won't be be able to use the multimedia keys on your keyboard to go above 100%.

Credits: [Duong Phan posted this](https://plus.google.com/106709818726750214323/posts/9y23kpJc7D8) in elementary's Google+ community.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install `dconf-editor`
2. navigate to `/org/gnome/desktop/sound/allow-volume-above-100-percent`
3. set it `true`

You can't set it from UI but from keyboard shortcut or volume function key